# Translate C# Linq to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I could use some help converting this C# line of code to VB. I am very new to Linq and am having trouble with the syntax...

```
var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();
```

I have tried a number of online conversion tools and none of them have gotten it right either.

UPDATE:
Here is the full code block....

```
protected void MoveGridViewRows(object sender, EventArgs e)  {      
    Button btnUp = (Button)sender;      
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btnUp.NamingContainer;      
    // Get all items except the one selected      
    var rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>().Where(a => a != row).ToList();      
    switch (btnUp.CommandName)      
    {          
         case "Up":              
         //If First Item, insert at end (rotating positions)              
              if (row.RowIndex.Equals(0))
                  rows.Add(row);              
              else                 
                  rows.Insert(row.RowIndex - 1, row);              
                  break;          
         case "Down":              
         //If Last Item, insert at beginning (rotating positions)              
              if (row.RowIndex.Equals(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1))                  
                  rows.Insert(0, row);              
              else                 
                  rows.Insert(row.RowIndex + 1, row);              
                  break;      
         }      
         GridView1.DataSource = rows.Select(a => new     
         {          
              FirstName = ((TextBox)a.FindControl("txtFirstName")).Text,          
              LastName = ((TextBox)a.FindControl("txtLastName")).Text,      
         }).ToList();      
         GridView1.DataBind();  
}
```

The specific error in VS on compile is....

Error   11  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'System.Func(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow, Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Also...

Error   12  Name 'a' is not declared.   C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\vv_home\roeMgr.aspx.vb  51  46  C:\

HERE is the VB code thus far.....

```
    Protected Sub MoveGridViewRows(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


    Dim btnUp As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnUp.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    ' Get all items except the one selected      
    Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a IsNot row).ToList()


    Select Case btnUp.CommandName
        Case "Up"
            'If First Item, insert at end (rotating positions)              
            If row.RowIndex.Equals(0) Then
                rows.Add(row)
            Else
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex - 1, row)
            End If
            Exit Select
        Case "Down"
            'If Last Item, insert at beginning (rotating positions)              
            If row.RowIndex.Equals(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                rows.Insert(0, row)
            Else
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex + 1, row)
            End If
            Exit Select
    End Select
    GridView1.DataSource = rows.[Select](a >= New With { _
     .FirstName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox).Text, _
     .LastName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox).Text _
    }).ToList()
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

thanks,

Comment: What did the online conversion tools generate?  What errors did they result in?

Comment: Your edit still doesn't address @Servy's question - I'm not sure how the full code block helps.  That being said, I'll update my answer to convert the whole thing.

Comment: Online tools report this as VB....Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList().................But in VS editor code fails as indicated below on your answser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a IsNot row).ToList()
```

for the other, should be

```
GridView1.DataSource = rows.Select(Function(a) New With {_         
              .FirstName = CType(a.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox).Text,_
              .LastName = CType(a.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox).Text_      
         }).ToList()
```

Comment: Yup, I just noticed that while comparing our otherwise identical answers. ;-)

Comment: Updated post of full C# code block.  The issue is the two lines LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I'd say:

```
dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList()
```

but I'm not in a position to test that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList()
```

Comment: I posted this before I saw that Chris had made his correction - Chris's answer is correct (except for the semi-colon).

Comment: your edit on Bobson's post fixed the first error. I am still getting a 'Name a is not declared' error on this line......GridView1.DataSource = rows.[Select](a >= New With

Comment: Bobson's conversion of that statement looks good to me - except that you can simply use "Select" instead of "[Select]" (VB knows that 'Select' is not used as a keyword in this context).

Comment: thanks, it was this part that fixed it - "a <> row" should be "a IsNot row". can you tell me there is a way to iterate through the gridview on the last Datasource line....    GridView1.DataSource = rows.[Select](Function(a) New With { _ 
        Key .FirstName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox).Text, _ 
        Key .LastName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox).Text _ 
    }).ToList() 
.....This was obviously written for the example, in reality my grid has many more cols. I'd like to iterate through them to rebuild data source. Can post new thread if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

According to [this converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), it's

```
 Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList()
```

That looks right to me.

---

Since you posted the full code block, here's the result of converting the whole thing:

```
Protected Sub MoveGridViewRows(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim btnUp As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnUp.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    ' Get all items except the one selected      
    Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList()
    Select Case btnUp.CommandName
        Case "Up"
            'If First Item, insert at end (rotating positions)              
            If row.RowIndex.Equals(0) Then
                rows.Add(row)
            Else
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex - 1, row)
            End If
            Exit Select
        Case "Down"
            'If Last Item, insert at beginning (rotating positions)
            If row.RowIndex.Equals(GridView1.Rows.Count - 1) Then
                rows.Insert(0, row)
            Else
                rows.Insert(row.RowIndex + 1, row)
            End If
            Exit Select
    End Select
    GridView1.DataSource = rows.[Select](Function(a) New With { _
        Key .FirstName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtFirstName"), TextBox).Text, _
        Key .LastName = DirectCast(a.FindControl("txtLastName"), TextBox).Text _
    }).ToList()
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: And seeing that makes me *really* glad I don't work with VB any more.   So unwieldy...

Comment: Line fails on Function(a); a is not defined.

Comment: Overload fails because no accessible 'Where' clause can be called with these arguments. Error on this row ....Dim rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)().Where(Function(a) a <> row).ToList

Comment: @marc11h - That sounds like you don't have the LINQ references.  Can you confirm that you have a reference to System.Data.Linq in your project and an `Imports` in your file?

Comment: Thanks Bobson for the translation, I can cut and paste to the translators too, the issue was with the LINQ translations which doesn't work after the conversion. My original post indicate that LINQ was the issue the translators don't report errors on LINQ.

Comment: I do have the IMPORT added for LINQ

Comment: @marc11h - That **is** the correct syntax.  I just confirmed it with a `List(Of Int32)`.

Comment: Two things - "a <> row" should be "a IsNot row", and "Exit Select" here is unnecessary and very non-standard.